# Kendo UI Grid row onBlur event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo ui grid and I want to bind onBlur event on the row. I'm using the code below:

```
$('#grid').on('blur', 'tr.k-state-selected', function (e) {                         
    var grid = gridControl.data('kendoGrid')
        ,cell = grid.select()                                                   
        ,selectedItem = grid.dataItem(cell);

    console.log(selectedItem);
});
```

My problem is, the onBlur event is also firing when I select a cell in the same row. I don't want to fire the onBlur event when I navigate on the cell within the same row. What I need is to only fire the onBlur event when I lost focus on the row.

Comment: You should use the change event and check if you just selected something or deselected something.

Comment: Or you could have a fun time hunting through the Telerik docs for it. :)